# PHP form sending mail to all users instead of just one

Tags: php, mysql, email, while-loop

I'm creating a web page where users can create posts. Other users can reply to the post by filling out a form which sends an email to the post creator.
I iterate with while loop to show all posts from MySQL db and at the same time show form for replying.

The problem I'm having is, when I press the send button on the reply form, all users from the db gets an email. The way it should work is, the person I'm replying to should get the email. Tried other iterators. Thinking about using objects but just can't understand why when I press the send button mail() function sends an email to all users.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msg ORDER by id DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    print '<div class="block">
                <div id="uMail">
                    <a id="mail" href="'.$row['userMail'].'"> <img src="mail.png" > </a>
                </div>

                <div id="uName">
                    <span id="var">'.$row['userName'].'</span>
                </div>

                <div id="uMsg">
                    <p>'.$row['userMsg'].'</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="popup">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div id="sName">
                        <input type="text" name="sName" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="sMail">
                        <input type="email" name="sMail" />
                    </div>
                        <textarea name="sMsg"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
                </form> 
            </div>
            ';

    if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
        $usrMail = $row['userMail'];
        $sndrName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sName"]);
        $sndrMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sMail']);
        $sndrMsg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sMsg"]);

        mail($usrMail, "Hey", $sndrMsg);
        header('location: forma.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean wana send a mail to particular id? from the database

Comment: Hey Mantas Pi are you there

Comment: Yes, to email of post author, not others

Answer (score 3):

1. Because sendmail() is inside the while().
2. I highly recommend https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer for sending E-Mails, because mail() cannot specify a SMTP.

Comment: if i make mail() outside while, just last user in db gets email. im stuck

Comment: Do you know author Id whom you want to shoot mail?

Comment: That's because $row['userMail'] holds the last entry once the while has finished. You have to make sure the correct $row['userMail'] is posted when someone clicks the submit button.

Comment: @DidarAlam  yes its in db.

Comment: @user3606329 i understand that, just dont know how to do that. usually when make if statement in iterator it works just in particular iteration, and here its just not working. i do in while an if statement if(isset($_POST...) $ usrMail =$row['userMail'], but i get last value :)

Comment: What i have understood your requirements is, when your press the reply button should mail send to an specific user or users with what data's you want to send him/her/them. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are redirecting the user to forma.php after sending one email. You should move this line:

```
header('location: forma.php');
```

outside the while loop, so the user is redirected after all emails are sent

Comment: i even got rid of this line, but just the same, if mail is in while and in if(isset{$_POST...)) it just send email for all users and not one, if mail outside while, it sends to last user in db :(

Comment: Well, your while loop runs for all users, so it sends email to all users. One possible solution is that you make the name of your input fields unique. For example add a variable inside while loop called $count and add it to each input field name. For example <input type="text" name="sName'.$count.'" />. You should also update your email code so it uses the new field names. For example $_POST["sName".$count]

Comment: yes Nadir, i made button name $i, and $i++ in while loop, and it works :) now made pop up form with javascript but cant think how to send email value to that form, because form is outside while :)

Answer (score 0):

so finally i made it, i just made submit button name as $i, which is $i++ in while cycle. then i made if(isset($_POST["$i"])) inside while with mail function and its working :)
But, now i want to make popup form for answering and have no idea how to manage it :)